# Is there a free video player which can play any type of video?

Tags: lumia-520

Can I download an app or codec for my Lumia 520. I need a media player which can play any kind of video, especially .avi .mkv.

Comment: I'm still waiting for the official VLC app. But I guess it will be released in 2015.

Comment: Download VLC... Best video player for windows phone..

Answer (score 6):

The popular [VLC player](https://www.windowsphone.com/en-gb/store/app/vlc-for-windows-phone/44fa83f7-a98d-4647-b9d4-c35ed729d0c9) is available in the store for free.

Comment: Vlc supports Avi format. But does that have a full screen option. Cant find such option in lumia 520........

Comment: in playback just turn your phone sideways and touch the screen once to hide all controls.

Answer (score 3):

There are several apps that are able to play `avi` or `mkv` files. I did a quick Google search on [**Windows Phone 8 mkv**](https://www.google.com/search?q=windows%20phone%208%20mkv). Here are some examples:

- [**MoliPlayer Pro**](http://www.windowsphone.com/nl-be/store/app/moliplayer-pro/19ea6d3e-e3d9-401d-b30a-f6471811fe08) (costs 2.99, good score after 78 reviews)
- [**CCPlayer**](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/ccplayer/877817e5-2496-4e1f-a2f8-8f92ef829a83) (free, 4/5 after 400 reviews)

It's up to you to install, I didn't try any of them. I just want to show that there are apps available for playing videos with mkv format.

Answer (score 1):

Use **CCPlayer** to see videos in windows phone. This is free and will play most of the video formats and also have options to view subtitles, etc.